# rich:calendar defaultLabel attribute causes conversion error

Tags: java, jsf, richfaces

Using the defaultLabel attribute of the Rich Faces Calendar component correctly displays the reminder text for the date format like I would like it to.  However, when this reminder text is on an optional field, then a conversion error occurs as if it was trying to convert the reminder text into a date.

```
<rich:calendar enableManualInput="true" value="#{participantSummaryManagedBean.dob}"
    id="dob" locale="US" popup="true" datePattern="MMddyyyy" defaultLabel="MMDDYYYY"
    showApplyButton="false" converterMessage="Use MMDDYYYY format">
</rich:calendar>
```

Confirmed in RichFaces versions 4.2.2.Final, 4.2.3.Final, and 4.3.0.20121024-M2

Is there a way to prevent or get around this?

Comment: It looks like a bug in RichFaces component. Report it to RichFaces guys and they will give you a proper answer.

Comment: Thanks Luiggi.  I have submitted a JIRA.  We will see what happens.  https://issues.jboss.org/browse/RF-12594

Comment: For what it's worth adding a onclick on the commandButton that checks to see if the value of the input box still equals the defaultLabel and setting the value to blank will get around this issue.  I have put this in the JIRA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a defect in Richfaces (https://issues.jboss.org/browse/RF-12594). 
However, from 4.3 on (specifically 4.3.0.20121214-M3 on), defaultLabel is deprecated and replaced by the tag `rich:placeholder`.  For example:

```
<rich:calendar value="#{bean.dob}" id="dob" popup="true" datePattern="MMddyyyy" converterMessage="Use MMDDYYYY format" enableManualInput="true">
  <rich:placeholder value="MMDDYYYY" />
</rich:calendar>
```